# Why is $\hat f(\xi)/\xi\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ when $f\in L^1$ is odd,$\hat f'(0)$ exists, and $\hat f(\xi)$ always has the same sign as $\xi$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, even-and-odd-functions

I need to prove:

If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is an odd function such that its Fourier Transform $\hat{f}$ is differentiable at $\xi = 0$ and $\hat{f} \geq 0$ when $\xi \geq 0$, then $\hat{f}(\xi)/\xi \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

My work so far:

I have established (using only $f$ being odd) that we have $$\Gamma = \sup_{\alpha \geq 1} \left|\int_1^\alpha \frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi} \, d\xi\right| < \infty.$$ Now, $$\left\|\frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi}\right\| = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|\frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi}\right| \, d\xi= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi} \, d\xi \\= 2 \left(\int_0^1  \frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi} \, d\xi + \int_1^\infty  \frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi} \, d\xi\right) \leq 2\int_0^1  \frac{\hat{f}(\xi)}{\xi} \, d\xi+2\Gamma.$$ I am unsure how to proceed from here. I have not made use of assumption that $\hat{f}'(0)$ exists, but I am not sure how to use it.

As a follow-up: seems like a lot of questions on here have talked a lot about functions being odd and considering the Fourier Transform. Is there a particular reason, or is the theory for even functions simplified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is odd, then note that $$\int_{\mathbb R} f dx = \hat f(0)=0.$$
From the definition of differentiability, there exists $C\in\mathbb R$ such that
$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\hat f(h)-\hat f(0)}h = C$$
as we have that $\hat f(0)=0$, this actually says that

$$ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\hat f(h) }h = C$$

And hence $\hat f(\xi)/\xi$ is a bounded function on the set $|\xi|<1$. The integrability follows.

(Its not clear to me where $\xi\ge0 \implies \hat f(\xi)\ge0$ would be used?)

Comment: How does this imply boundedness on the interval $|\xi| < 1$?

Comment: @HrafnMagnus it implies that there is a small ball $B_{\epsilon}(0)$ on which $|\hat f(\xi)/\xi| \le 1+2|C|$. Outside of this ball, $\hat f$ is bounded and the denominator is bounded away from zero. Ergo the result

Comment: Could you perhaps provide more detail?

Comment: @HrafnMagnus well, I don't really know what more detail I could provide. I will gladly respond to questions. Perhaps, you should open the definition of $"\lim_{h\to 0}"$?

Comment: I am just unsure of the inequality you have $|\hat{f}(\xi)/\xi| \leq 1+2|C|$ ...

Comment: @HrafnMagnus, ok, but you agree that the limit is finite($C$)? Can you write the definition of the limit out?

Comment: Yes I understand that we can make $|\hat{f}(\xi)/\xi - C| < \epsilon$ for some $|\xi| < \delta$.

Comment: @HrafnMagnus ok, and you can do this for any $\epsilon>0$. So if you choose arbitrarily $\epsilon=|C|+1$ Then for a small ball around 0, triangle inequality gives $$| \hat f(\xi)/\xi| \le |\hat f(\xi)/\xi-C|+|C|\le 2|C|+1$$ as claimed.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answers!